# Куда делся перенос вопроса с меты?

Tags: поддержка, мета, перенос-вопросов

На основном сайте есть такой вариант закрытия:

> В сети Stack Exchange есть другой сайт, более подходящий для этого вопроса.

И дальше там можно выбрать мету.

А как перенести вопрос в другйю сторону - с меты на основной сайт?

[image: скриншот с меты]

Comment: А он был? На enSO я тоже такого не вижу. Правда смотрю флаги (ибо репа).

Comment: @alexolut, может и не было, но логично же, чтоб был.

Comment: видимо это настолько редкая ситуация, что только модераторами может разруливаться. Типа чтоб на Мету писать надо уже на основном сайте репу набить.

Comment: Модератор может, я вчера переносил с меты на основной.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ага, я заметил. Как раз его и хотел.